# What period is considered by fortinet for the policy information last used / hit count?

Tags: firewall, policy

**Details**:

- To extract those information, you can go in the fortimanager > Policy & Objects > See the firewall policy of the desired firewall.
- Then you can display the columns "hit count" and "last used" but they are empty by default, you have to recalculate them.
- For that, put your mouse over the column name "hit count" and you see a bouton "Refresh Now". Click on it: it fills the columns with data.

**My questions are then**:

1. Will the "last used" date go back to the creation of the rule in the policy ? Or is it possible that this "last used" information misses some old hits ? Same question for the hit count: is there a limit in time where we can go back to get that number ?
2. If I delete the log history on the fortinet because they are taking too much space, does it impact the "hit count" calculation ? It seems that its not but I am not sure.
3. Are those "hit count" / "last used" data reset when you reboot the server ? When you update it ?

On this official fortinet documentation I found this page : [https://help.fortinet.com/fmgr/50hlp/60/6-0-0/Content/FortiManager_Admin_Guide/1000_Policy%20and%20Objects/1000_Managing%20policies/0025_Policy_hits.htm#:~:text=The%20hit%20count%20is%20collected,variable%20and%20the%20hitcount_concurrent%20variable](https://help.fortinet.com/fmgr/50hlp/60/6-0-0/Content/FortiManager_Admin_Guide/1000_Policy%20and%20Objects/1000_Managing%20policies/0025_Policy_hits.htm#:%7E:text=The%20hit%20count%20is%20collected,variable%20and%20the%20hitcount_concurrent%20variable).

It explains us that the hitcount (and I guess last used parameter too?) is calculated every 5 minutes by default and that it can be reset.

However I still don't understand what history is to consider and if it is reset, then how to get the date of the last reset to know what period is considered ?